# How to select all text in Confluence expand macro in mac

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, confluence

I am trying to find a way to select all text in a expand macro on confluence page on Macbook pro.

i.e. How to **select all text** in **expand macro** on confluence page?

Answer (score 1):

I can only think about using the tool "inspect element" of the browser
Then, from the HTML code, you are able to select all the text